# How can I open an element menu using element-ui?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I have a menu and want to open an element manually with a method but I can't find any info about how can I do it.

HTML

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.4.5/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<el-menu default-active="2" class="el-menu-vertical-demo" @open="handleOpen" @close="handleClose">
<el-submenu index="1">
  <template slot="title">
    <i class="el-icon-location"></i>
    <span>Navigator One</span>
  </template>
  <el-menu-item-group title="Group One">
    <el-menu-item index="1-1">item one</el-menu-item>
    <el-menu-item index="1-2">item one</el-menu-item>
  </el-menu-item-group>
  <el-menu-item-group title="Group Two">
    <el-menu-item index="1-3">item three</el-menu-item>
  </el-menu-item-group>
  <el-submenu index="1-4">
    <template slot="title">item four</template>
    <el-menu-item index="1-4-1">item one</el-menu-item>
  </el-submenu>
</el-submenu>
<el-menu-item index="2">
  <i class="el-icon-menu"></i>
  <span>Navigator Two</span>
</el-menu-item>
<el-menu-item index="3" disabled>
  <i class="el-icon-document"></i>
  <span>Navigator Three</span>
</el-menu-item>
<el-menu-item index="4">
  <i class="el-icon-setting"></i>
  <span>Navigator Four</span>
</el-menu-item>
</el-menu>
</div>
```

JS

```
Main = {
methods: {
  handleOpen(key, keyPath) {
    console.log(key, keyPath);
  },
  handleClose(key, keyPath) {
    console.log(key, keyPath);
  }
}
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

The idea is to be able to toogle the open and close of the first element of the menu manually not only on click

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/aL4w1zgr/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but you could add a `ref` attribute to the `el-menu` element

```
<el-menu default-active="2" class="el-menu-vertical-demo" @open="handleOpen" @close="handleClose" ref="menu" >
```

and then trigger the "open" menu event in this way:

```
this.$refs.menu.open(1);
```

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL4w1zgr/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `collapse` attribute to el-menu:

```
<el-menu
  default-active="2"
  class="el-menu-vertical-demo"
  @open="handleOpen"
  @close="handleClose"
  :collapse="isCollapse"
>
```

Then add data:

```
Main = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      isCollapse: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleOpen(key, keyPath) {
      console.log(key, keyPath);
    },
    handleClose(key, keyPath) {
      console.log(key, keyPath);
    }
  }
}
```

And now you can programatically open / close menu with toggling the isCollapse value, or direct assigning to true or false state.